# A name for "not quite saturated" graded modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, terminology

Let $M$ be a finitely generated graded module over a graded ring $R$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the corresponding coherent sheaf on $\operatorname{Proj} R$.  There is a natural map of graded $R$-modules
$$\phi \colon M \to \Gamma^*(\mathcal{F}) := \bigoplus_{n} \Gamma(\operatorname{Proj} R, \mathcal{F}(n)).$$
If I recall Ravi Vakil's notes correctly, $M$ is called *saturated* if $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

> Is there a term (perhaps semi-saturated, or some such) for modules $M$ such that $\phi$ is injective?

This concept is appealing for several reasons.  For one thing, it is easier to test "semi-saturatedness" than saturatedness; e.g., unless I am mistaken, $\phi$ is automatically injective if $M$ admits any positive-degree homogeneous nonzerodivisor.  For another, at least if $R$ is a polynomial ring, $M = R/I$ is "semi-saturated" iff $I$ is a saturated ideal of $R$.  (Note that the definition of "saturated ideal" is different from the definition given above for "saturated module", and I do not think the two are equivalent for ideals.)

Comment: I don't know a name for this, but I have a comment.
This is quite close to being torsion free (or more precisely, $R_+$-torsion free) if $\mathcal{F}$ is already S2.

Ok, for example, lets suppose that $R$ is normal and $\mathcal{F}$ is reflexive on $X$ (this is equivalent to S2, depending on your choice of terms).  Then $\Gamma^*(\mathcal{F})$ is the S2-ification = reflexification of $M$.  There's a paper of Hartshorne called something like "Generalized divisors on Gorenstein schemes" where he points out that in the context I described, the injectivity is  equivalent to being torsion free.

Comment: You can make sense of this even without the reflexification statements too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate on Karl's comment:

Let $m$ be the irrelevant ideal of $R$, then there is a short exact sequence:

$$0 \to H_m^0(M) \to  M \to \Gamma^*(\mathcal{F}) \to H_m^1(M) \to 0$$

(see Eisenbud's book, Theorem A4.1, p. 693). Here $H_m^i(M)$ denote the local cohomology modules. So the map is injective precisely when $H_m^0(M):= \cup_n (0:_M m^n) = 0$. I believe such module is called $m$-*torsion-free* (don't know a reference off hand, may be Brodmann-Sharp's book on local cohomology?).

Also, it is equivalent to $m$ contains a non-zerodivisor on $M$ (may be that's what you meant in the last paragraph?)

Answer (score 3):

As Hailong wrote, the injectivity means the vanishing of $H^0_m(M)$. But $\operatorname{depth}(m,M)$ is the least non-vanishing local cohomology, thus the map $M \to H^0_*(\tilde{M})$ is injective iff $M$ has depth $\ge$ 1.
If $M$ has finite projective dimension, e.g. if R is regular, then this happens iff $M$ has projective dimension at most depth $R-1$ by the Auslander-Buchsbaum formula.